# Using Aync Task For Android Game

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a Whack-a-mole game in Android Studio and I'm having a hard time with AsyncTask (our teacher told us to use it).

Basically the AsyncTasks are not doing anything.

I tried using one asynctask to increase an int and change a textview with the new value each time it increased and it worked, however it doesn't work for what I want it to do.

```
TextView tv;

ImageView iv1;
ImageView iv2;
ImageView iv3;
ImageView iv4;

boolean salir = false;

int puntuacion = 0;
int vidas = 3;

Hilo hilo;
Hilo hilo2;
Hilo hilo3;
Hilo hilo4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    iv1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    iv4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    hilo = new Hilo(iv1);
    hilo2 = new Hilo(iv2);
    hilo3 = new Hilo(iv3);
    hilo4 = new Hilo(iv4);
    hilo.execute();
    hilo2.execute();
    hilo3.execute();
    hilo4.execute();

}

public void updatePuntuacion() {
    tv.setText("Puntuacion: " + puntuacion);
}

public void updateVidas() {

}

private class Hilo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    boolean estado = false;
    ImageView img;

    public Hilo (ImageView img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        while(!salir){

            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (estado) {
                        puntuacion++;
                        updatePuntuacion();
                    } else {
                        vidas--;
                        updateVidas();
                    }

                }
            });


            if(estado) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*5000+2000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.topo);
                estado=true;
                publishProgress();
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*3000+1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
                estado=false;
                publishProgress();
            }

            if(puntuacion == 100) {
                salir=true;
            }

            if(vidas == 0) {
                salir = true;
            }
        }
        return puntuacion;
    }
}
```

I expect the imageviews to change it's image every X secs (those are random) but they don't.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I noticed I spelled AsyncTask as AsincTask, sorry for that haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how an Async task works.
You cannot do all the work in "doInBackground" .

1. You need to remove the onClickListener form "doInBackground" .
2. Start your async task in the imageview onClick and
3. After your complete your background processing stuff in "doInBackground" , 
   set the  image to imageview in "onPostExecute" .

Please go through this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask 
to understand what an Async Task is first